# Put content into iframe and print it

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I can put content into the body of the iframe without problems, but I cannot put stuff into the header or into the whole html part of the iframe.

So it completely ignores all the @media and @page stuff I need for print and I think it is because it puts my code into the body part. (yes I use document.body, but I dont know what else to use)

here is my iframe

```
<iframe id="contentFrame"></iframe>
```

and here is the code

```
var myHtml = ''
+ '     <!DOCTYPE html>           '
+ '     <html>                    '
+ '     <head>                    '
+ '         <title>Testing</title>'
+ '         <meta charset="utf-8" />'
+ '         <style type="text/css"> '
+ '             @media print{       '
+ '                 @page {         '
+ '                     size: landscape;          '
+ '                     margin: 10mm 5mm 5mm 5mm; '
+ '                     mso-header-margin:0mm;    '
+ '                     mso-footer-margin:0mm;    '
+ '                     mso-paper-source:0;       '
+ '                 }                             '
+ '             }    '
+ '         </style> '
+ '     </head>      '
+ '     <body>       '
+ all-my-content-goes-here
+ '     </body>      '
+ '     </html>      '

window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML = myHtml;
```

and the result looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: You are setting the innerHTML of _body_, of course you can not put doctype, html and head in there ... This is one of the cases where you might want to use document.write instead.

Comment: Ahh yes - let me have a look at that one - totally forgot document.write :-D

Comment: That actually did the trick - but it still wont accept `size:landscape;`